# Apache Multiple VirtualDocumentRoot

Tags: apache, apache2

Using Apache2 on a Linux system is there a way to have multiple VirtualDocumentRoot using [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)?

This is naming convention I am currently using and would like to continue to use:

```
host                    directory
127.0.0.1 domain        domain.com
127.0.0.1 sub.domain    domain.com_sub
```

Then in my vhosts section of the httpd.conf I have:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0.0.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2.0.com_%1
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem with this is when I visit sub.domain the Apache error log shows that it is looking for /var/www/sub.domain.com rather than /var/www/domain.com_test which leads me to believe it only reads the first rule and then fails, but what I would like it to do is use any document root that satisfies either of the two VirtualDocumentRoot rules.

Comment: I'm assuming you solved this issue, but I've posted below for completeness, since this comes up in google searches.

You might want to mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 14):

Apache typically will pick the first virtual host whose `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` matches the host name provided in the `Host` HTTP header. In your case, since you have no `ServerName` directives, Apache supposedly uses a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address to fake a server name, and presuming that the reverse DNS leads to domain.com, which doesn't match, Apache then defaults to the first virtual host. Sounds complicated, I know... the bottom line is, you should use `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` to make the configuration explicit. Try something more like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2.%3_%1
</VirtualHost>
```

That should use `/var/www/domain.com` for http://domain.com and `/var/www/www.domain.com` for http://www.domain.com, both of which are served by the first vhost, and `/var/www/sub.domain.com` for http://sub.domain.com, `/var/www/blah.domain.com` for http://blah.domain.com, and so on.

Comment: This saved my day. I was switching between two VirtualHost files with VirtualDocumentRoot definitions. I knew there had to be a better way and you figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: The solution solved my problem. But I have a new question, for some special sub domains, I need do some special config, such as add JK config, or set a customized log file. How can we do that?

Comment: @Stony I suggest asking on [webmasters.SE] or perhaps [SF].

Answer (score 4):

You have to qualify the backreferences when you want to put a '.' in the file path. So you need to have it like this:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2.0.%3_%1
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the OP and the issue with "/var/www/html" being set:

The problem I had to this was using %1 instead of %2. Here's my working example:

```
ServerAlias www.*.org.au
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/sites/%2/pub
```

Hope that helps someone!

I read the docs on "Directory Name Interpolation" in [mod_vhost_alias docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a configuration that allows flexible subdomain creation.

See apache docs on [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)

If your root dev domain has 3 parts like dev.example.com you can use `%-4+` as a placeholder for everything before the root domain. If it has 4 parts, use `%-5+`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/%-4+/webroot"
    ServerName www.dev.example.com
    ServerAlias *.dev.example.com
    php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/setdocroot.php
</VirtualHost>
```

This way you can create a directory named `/var/www/sub.domain/webroot` and access it with the url `sub.domain.dev.example.com`.

The line `php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /var/www/setdocroot.php` fixes the docroot on some systems like OSX 10.9+

Here is the content of `setdocroot.php` :

```
<?php
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am noticing with this configuration is that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is pointing to  /var/www/html and not to the vhost's doc root.
weird.

Update (2010-07-24):

I just wrote a blog post how to setup your http proof server
http://www.devcha.com/2010/07/how-to-setup-your-http-proof-server.html